# Detect gap in time in r and calculate data accordingly

Tags: r

I have a dataframe temp which looks like the following:

```
Time       Count       Colour  
01:02:30  11.000000       Red  
17:05:49  52.000000       White  
04:06:07   4.000000       Blue  
01:07:03  30.000000       Red  
20:08:30   4.000000       Yellow
```

The Time was initially an ISODate do I stripped it off to get the time, which is what I wanted, using the code below.

```
temp$Time = parse_iso_8601(temp$Time)  
temp$Time <- as.POSIXlt(temp$Time)  
library(chron)  
temp$Time=times(format(temp$Time, format="%H:%M:%S"))
```

There are gaps between the Time in the data. I wish to find out the rows one hour post the gap and one hour before the gap. e.g after 1 am there is a gap of 3 hours, so I wish to find the rows for 12-1 am and also 4-5 am. How can I detect the gap and get the required rows from my dataframe?

Also to get the rows between 12am and 1am what should I do?
This doesn't seem to work!

```
temp[temp$Time >= 24/24 & temp$Time <= 1/24, ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you've converted your times to `chron`, you can perform the comparison as follows:

```
temp[temp$Time >= times("00:00:00", format=c('h:m:s')) & temp$Time <= times("01:00:00", format=c('h:m:s')), ]
```

In the example you've posted there is no time between 00:00 and 01:00, this is an example from 1:00 to 2:00:

```
> temp[temp$Time >= times("01:00:00", format=c('h:m:s')) & temp$Time <= times("02:00:00", format=c('h:m:s')), ]
      Time Count Colour
1 01:02:30    11    Red
4 01:07:03    30    Red
```

Hope it helps.